# g++ internal server error with alias templates

Tags: c++, c++17

This is a simple code I used for alias templates and g++ 10.2(homebrew) on mac to compile it

```
#include <stack>
#include <deque>

template<typename T>
using DStack = std::stack<T, std::deque<T>>;

int main() {
    DStack stk;
}
```

g++ version is:
g++-10 (Homebrew GCC 10.2.0) 10.2.0
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Compiled with this command line:
`g++-10 -std=c++17 typealias2.cpp`

And the output is:

```
typealias2.cpp: In function 'int main()':
typealias2.cpp:8:12: warning: alias template deduction only available with '-std=c++2a' or '-std=gnu++2a'<br>
    8 |     DStack stk;<br>
      |            ^~~
typealias2.cpp:8:12: internal compiler error: in set_constraints, at cp/constraint.cc:1190<br>
libbacktrace could not find executable to open


Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/issues> for instructions.
```

I know that I missed the template argument for DStack at line 8.  The error should have beed something like **"missing template argument"**, instead I get an internal compiler error.

Checked with clang++ version 12, the error message is right on spot.

```
typealias2.cpp:8:12: error: alias template 'DStack' requires template arguments; argument deduction only allowed for class templates
    DStack stk;
           ^
typealias2.cpp:5:1: note: template is declared here
using DStack = std::stack<T, std::deque<T>>;
^
1 error generated.
```

By providing the template argument for DStack, the error goes away. Is this a g++ 10.2 bug?

Comment: `internal compiler error`: Wouldn't be the [g++ bug report site](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/) the better place for this issue?

Comment: internal compiler errors are always compiler bugs, reproducible on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/3WPK17) though only with `-std=c++17`. `-std=c++14` and `-std=c++20` both work correctly. seems to be broken from gcc 10 onwards and is still broken in trunk